# How can you add multiple users in a Kotlin Login?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to add more users in a Login app made with Kotlin, there's no database or whatever, the accounts are hardcoded into the program, I heard about using arrays but I'm not too sure on how to implement it in this context.

Thank you to anyone who reads this.

```
package com.example.textandviewbinding

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.textandviewbinding.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import java.util.*
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        binding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
            validateUser(it)
        }
    }

    private fun addTextView(text:String){
        val textView1 = TextView(this)
        textView1.text = text
        textView1.textSize = 16f
        textView1.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
        binding.myLayout.addView(textView1)
    }



    private fun validateUser(it: View) {
        val username = binding.editUsername.text
        val password = binding.editPassword.text
        if (username.toString().equals("joed", ignoreCase = true) && password.toString().equals("1234")) {

    //              Toast.makeText(this, "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val message = getString(R.string.welcome_message,username)


         Snackbar.make(it, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Show details.. ", { addTextView("Login Successful: ${Calendar.getInstance().time}" ) })
            .show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            exitProcess(-1)
        }
    }

    private fun displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful ${Calendar.getInstance().time}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- Create a class called User , ex:

```
data class User(
var id : Int
var name : String
)
```

2- Create an Array of users using the User model in your MainActivity :

```
private val users = ArrayList<User>()
```

3- Add users to the array :

```
users.add(User(1,"Alex"))
users.add(User(2,"Andrei"))
```

Comment: And if necessary, the data class can be extended by the password.